# bash q4u - how to append value in different file matching on userid in column1

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, append

Thanks for looking. I've tried various awk, sed, paste, cut commands - arg.
Looking for a bash solution.

I have two files - file1 is a csv of attributes for each user, beginning with userid in col1.
in file2 lists userid and another unique attribute, matching each userid in file1

how can i write a 'for i in' , or 'while read line' on file1, store the userid on each line in file1 on col1 , search file2 for the userid and then store the 2nd value (listed like this userid,uniqueAttribute), and that append that uniqueAttribute at the end of the stored line in file1 (or a new file with the entire line from file1,uniqueAttribute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use `read` to extract fields into different variables in particular the key.  Then you find the matching row in the other table, you could do it with grep, or you could read that file into an array and write a function that finds the relevant line for  a given key.  Apparently, there is query tool for csv files called miller.  I would check that out if I was you.  It may sound super overkill, but don't overlook reading these two files into two sqlite3 tables.  Now you can write a simple query to extract the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

file1.csv:

```
userid,first_name
bob,Robert
jane,Janice
```

file2.csv:

```
userid,unicorn
bob,yes
jane,no
```

and here super simple script that correlates the two:

```
while IFS=, read userid first_name
do
    echo "$userid,$first_name,$(grep ^$userid file2.csv | cut -d, -f2)"
done < file1.csv
```

and the output would be:

```
userid,first_name,unicorn                                                                                              
bob,Robert,yes                                             
jane,Janice,no
```

You asked for a loop but `join` would give you the same result:

```
join -t, file1.csv file2.csv
```